# How can I create an excel like sheet with flutter widgets?

Tags: flutter

I have a spreadsheet, with about 100 rows and 30 columns I want to show on my app.

I am looking to do something like this: [image]

My needs:

- Each cell should be Tappable
- Can scroll to a specific cell programmatically
- Is Not expensive to build

I was successful in creating this with `Table` (UI) + `InteractiveViewer` (allows zooming and scrolling bidirectionally) but it is very very heavy on the build, each build takes a toll on performance so I thought about using `GridView.builder` + `InteractiveViewer` which hopefully alleviates build a bit (still testing).

What do you think I should do for this project?

Comment: does you have video to show how smooth/heavy the app you running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is also a way to use a famous package

ex.)

https://pub.dev/packages/pluto_grid

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_layout_grid

But what comes to mind right now is to configure only that page as a webview.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/pluto_grid This package was the solution to my problem, it has everything.